# What does this program in Prolog do?

Tags: prolog

What is the purpose of this:

```
route(Town1,Town2,Distance):-
 road(Town1,Town2,Distance).
```

Also, what does `!` mean in this context? If someone knows exactly what it means, because all I hear is "cut" without any other explanation.

```
%TRAVELLING SALESMAN PROBLEM
DOMAINS
 town = symbol
 distance = integer
 
PREDICATES
 nondeterm road(town,town,distance)
 nondeterm route(town,town,distance)
 
 CLAUSES
 road("tampa","houston",200).
 road("gordon","tampa",300).
 road("houston","gordon",100).
 road("houston","kansas_city",120).
 road("gordon","kansas_city",130).
 
route(Town1,Town2,Distance):-
 road(Town1,Town2,Distance).
 
 route(Town1,Town2,Distance):-
 road(Town1,X,Dist1),
 route(X,Town2,Dist2),
 Distance=Dist1+Dist2, !.

GOAL
 route("tampa", "kansas_city", X),
 write("Distance from Tampa to Kansas City is ",X),nl.
```

Comment: I recommend taking an afternoon (or two) to check this channel on youtube: [The Power of Prolog](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCFFeNyzCEQDS4KCecugmotg)

Comment: ```!``` means once you've found one solution, stop and don't try to find any more. I'll write up an official answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

Prolog programs use recursion heavily, which is why you need a base case for the recursion to stop. Here:

```
route(Town1,Town2,Distance):-
    road(Town1,Town2,Distance).
```

We're saying "If there's a direct road between `Town1` and `Town2`, then we're done, no need to check for a route through any other town because this *is* a route, just give me the distance." In other words, we are saying "If there is a defined clause that matches the first two arguments, what must `Distance` be to fully match it?"

The `!` is the `cut/1` predicate. It stops backtracking. [Here it is, described more thoroughly](https://boklm.eu/prolog/page_5.html#:%7E:text=Prolog%20provides%20a%20predicate%20that,fail%20without%20trying%20other%20alternatives.):

> Sometimes it is desirable to selectively turn off backtracking. Prolog provides a predicate that performs this function. It is called the cut/1, represented by an exclamation point (!).

> The cut/1 effectively tells Prolog to freeze all the decisions made so far in this predicate. That is, if required to backtrack, it will automatically fail without trying other alternatives.

In the case of your code:

```
 route(Town1,Town2,Distance):-
     road(Town1,X,Dist1),
     route(X,Town2,Dist2),
     Distance=Dist1+Dist2, !.
```

You are telling Prolog that, if you find a road between `Town1` and Town `X`, and then from Town `X` there is a route to finish of the path between `Town1` and `Town2`, then recurse; if there is a direct road between `X` and `Town2`, then the predicate at the top of your question holds. If not, it will recursively loop. Eventually, `Dist2` will have a final value which will float back up to this predicate.

This is where `!` comes in. Once you have a route that holds, it says "Stop, don't try and find another route, I only want 1 route. Don't backtrack for any other possible routes." Otherwise, you'd get multiple `write("Distance from Tampa to Kansas City is ",X),nl.` with different `X` values, which might not have made sense to the author of this program.

Also, as @DavidTonhofer says, the `=` should be replaced with `is` as the latter will force arithmetic evaluation. For example `X = 2+4` compares `X` to the unevaluated expression `2+4`, but with `is` you'll be comparing `X` to `6`.

Comment: I'm not too confident I didn't make an error in this answer; it's my first ```prolog``` answer. If that's the case, feel free to edit and correct.

Comment: Yes, `!` means "commit to the current clause". Don't try any other clause for this  predicate and don't backtrack to the left of '!'. This is why clauses can often be read as : `head :- guard_to_test_preconditions, !, additional_computation.`.

Comment: It is also easier to read the `route(Town1,Town2,Distance)` clause as the statement: _The route between `Town1` and `Town2` has distance `Distance` **IF** there is a road from `Town1` to `X` with `Dist1`, **AND** there is a route from `X` to `Town2` with distance `Dist2` **AND** `Distance` is the sum of `Dist1` and `Dist2`_ (although that `=` should be an `is`). This explains why one can call `route(tampa,gordon,300)` and Prolog says YES. The cut commits to the first solution found.

Comment: The fun part of the "cut" is that it regularly forces you to step back and think again about what Prolog is actually doing and re-ascertain your programming reflexes. It never gets old.